# How to test if following-sibling tag has specific attribute value?

Tags: xslt

Example xml:

```
<body>
<macroField dictTag="comment"></macroField>
<macroField dictTag="comment"></macroField>
<macroField dictTag="comment"></macroField>
<macroField dictTag="comment"></macroField>
<macroField dictTag="stopName">Old Wisconsin </macroField>
<macroField dictTag="stopName">Another stop</macroField>
<macroField dictTag="stopName">Another stop</macroField>
</body>
```

I need to transform comments into divs but after the last comment I want to add extra
text "STOPS: " before I show stop.

I tried this xsl for comment tag but for some reason it evaluates to true for every comment tag, not just for the last one:

```
   <xsl:template match="*[@dictTag = 'comment']">
    <div class="comment_line">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </div>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::macroField/@dictTag = 'stopName'">
        <p>STOPS</p>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

What is wrong with my xsl:if test? How do I modify it so that if statement evaluates to true only for the last comment element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following sibling could refer to ANY following sibling, not just the immediate one- a younger brother is still younger even if your the eldest, and he's the youngest of 3. Try this:

```
following-sibling::macroField[1]/@dictTag = 'stopName'
```

Which selects on the first following sibling.